# Django Rest Framework - Permitiendo espacios en blanco en un CharField

Tags: python, regex, djangorestframework, django-urls

Tengo el siguiente modelo, el cual en su atributo `name` quiero que se permitan nombres compuestos o espacios en blanco, por ejemplo `Real Madrid`

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        _('name'),
        max_length=30,
        primary_key=True,
        # unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and ./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                # r'^[\w.ñ@+-]+$',
                r'^[\d\/. ()\-+ ]+$',
                _('Enter a valid name team. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and ./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A team with that name already exists."),
        },
    )
```

Mi archivo urls.py, en el url `/api/teams` yo tengo una expresión regular que incluye el espacio en blanco de esta forma:

```
url(r'^api/teams/(?P<name>[-\w.]+(?:%20[-\w.]+)*)/?', include(router.urls,)),

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'teams', TeamViewSet)

urlpatterns = [

    # Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls,)),

    # url(r'^api/teams/(?P<name>[-\w. ]+)/?', include(router.urls,)),
    url(r'^api/teams/(?P<name>[-\w.]+(?:%20[-\w.]+)*)/?', include(router.urls,)),


    # If you're intending to use the browsable API you'll probably also want to add REST framework's
    # login and logout views.
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
        namespace='rest_framework'))

]
```

Mi serializador es:

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    name = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Team.objects.all(), message='Lo sentimos, ya existe un equipo con este nombre')])

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('url', 'name',)
```

My viewset es:

```
class TeamViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    lookup_value_regex = '[\w.ñ@+-]+'
    #lookup_value_regex = '[\d\/. ()\-+]+'
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeamSerializer
    filter_fields = ('name',)
```

Cuando creo un registro de un `Team` con un nombre compuesto o con espacios en blancos, no es posible renderizar el registro de ese equipo serializado y por el contrario obtengo este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que se pueda permitir en el URL `/api/teams/` con caracteres como '`. _ -`' y espacios en blanco para nombres compuestos
como `Real Madrid` por ejemplo ...

Hasta el momento yo puedo crear un URL /api/teams/`con caracteres como '`. _ -`'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo permitir espacios en blanco en ese attributo `name`?

Comment: Si bien no manejo Django, entiendo que las urls son decodificadas antes de compararlas, convirtiendo al `%20` nuevamente en espacio, por lo que el regex `r'^api/teams/(?P<name>[-\w.]+(?: [-\w.]+)*)/?'` *debería* funcionar. ¿Podrías probarlo para confirmarme?

Comment: @Mariano muchas gracias, en este momento tengo que volver a clonar el proyecto para probar. Apenas lo tenga listo en mi entorno de desarrollo te comento por acá.

Comment: @bgarcial Pudiste probar lo que te sugiere @Mariano?

Comment: @Julio hola, no no me funcionó.

Comment: Para salir de dudas, prueba con `r'^api/teams/(?P<name>.*?)/?'` Debería admitirlo todo. Solo para comprobar que el problema esté en la expresión regular. Te acepta así los nombres con espacios?

Comment: @Julio no no me acepta un nombre con espacios pero no se si el problema esté en mi `TeamViewSet` en el atributo `lookup_value_regex`. Tengo esta salida de error `During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'team-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 'Inter de Milan'}' not found. 4 pattern(s) tried: ['api/teams/(?P.*?)/?teams/(?P[\\w.ñ@+-]+)\\.(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/teams/(?P.*?)/?teams/(?P[\\w.ñ@+-]+)/$', 'api/teams/(?P[\\w.ñ@+-]+)\\.(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/teams/(?P[\\w.ñ@+-]+)/$']), another exception occurred:`

Comment: Prueba quitando el lookup_value_regex del viewset. También, en el error hace referencia a 4 expresiones regulares pero en tu código no veo ninguna de ellas... Además parece que no son correctas. Parece que intentan utilizar grupos de captura con nombre, pero no se les ha dado ningún nombre (?P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)[a-zA-Z.]+(?:(?: |%20|[_.-])[a-zA-Z.]+)*$
```

Como puedes ver [en esta demo](https://regex101.com/r/kLPBE3/1/), debería funcionar para:

```
Real Madrid
Real%20Madrid
A.S._Monaco-Falcao
```

Pero a su vez está pensada para evitar casos que podrían ser incorrectos como:

```
A...S._Monaco-Falcao
A.S.___Monaco-Falcao
A.S._Monaco--Falcao
----
_---_-  -
```